On the "Decrees of Urban VIII" Regarding the Veneration and Representation of Deceased Persons in the Manner of Saints
This post is a follow-up to On the Papal Bull (Sanctissimus Dominus Noster) of Urban VIII
On pg. 4 of St. Alphonsus Liguori's Glories of Mary, we find, for example, the following "Protest of the Author"---

And, according to the Wikipedia biography of Pope Urban VIII found here, we read under "Policy on Private Revelation":

In light of Geremia's answer in the aforementioned post, it seems that Wikipedia may have been wrong in their citation of the ``papal bull Sanctissimus Dominus Noster of 13 March 1625.''
It has been my observation that a "Protost" such as the one above by St. Alphonsus Liguori is not uncommon---with all professing their obedience to the decrees of Pope Urban VIII regarding the veneration (or representation in the manner of Saints) of individuals whose sanctity has not been officially recognized by the Catholic Church.
QUESTION: Can anyone shed some light (with references and/or verifiable examples) of what exactly these "Decrees of Urban VIII" are? Is there a papal bull in which they are contained or where they promulgated in some other fashion?
Thank you.

With regard to the date March 1625, could there be some calendrical issue in play? The new year was variously reckoned from January 1st or March 25th. So March 13th 1625 could be reckoned as 1624 or 1626. Just a suggestion.

@davidlol I didn't think of that; I just assumed that such dates found on websites would be in Gregorian years. And I assume that January 1 began the new year back then at the Vatican, but even that I'm not certain of. Many thanks for your comment.

On the "Decrees of Urban VIII" Regarding the Veneration and Representation of Deceased Persons in the Manner of Saint
In the papal bull entitled Sanctissimus Dominus Noster of 13 March 1625, Pope Urban instructed Catholics not to venerate the deceased or represent them in the manner of saints without Church sanction. It required a bishop's approval for the publication of private revelations.
From the nineteenth century onwards, it become common for Catholic books of popular devotion to holy individuals or in regards to private revelations to carry  some form of disclaimer, so as not to prejudice the final judgements of the Church in regards to some private revelation or the process of beatification or canonization of believed holy individuals.
One read in part: "In obedience to the decrees of Urban the Eighth, I declare that I have no intention of attributing any other than a purely human authority to the miracles, revelations, favours, and particular cases recorded in this book..."
In Sanctissimus Dominus Noster, the Catholic faithful are told not to have images of deceased persons reputed to have died in holiness with halos, laurels and rays around their head. The bull also states that no one can print anything on alleged private revelations without the consent of the local bishop or the Apostolic See. Any violations of the bull would incur punishment.

He reserved the beatification of saints to the Holy See and in a Bull, dated 30 October, 1625, forbade the representation with the halo of sanctity of persons not beatified or canonized, the placing of lamps, tablets, etc., before their sepulchres, and the printing of their alleged miracles or revelations. - Pope Urban VIII

Procurators of the causes of individuals involved in the beatification or canonization process are not to write about said individuals as if they were already beatified or canonized. Let the Church work out the intricacies of the canonization process correctly. Calling a Venerable a Saint could in fact harm the canonical process of canonization and could be seen a trying to establish the cult of a saint, that can clearly only be established by the pope himself.
I have read some biographies by procurators of various holy individuals and who have occasionally employed the term Blessed or Saint to someone, but in the protest, the procurator explicitly states that the term is used a popular belief that a person is holy and is not meant to be used as a way to influence the final canonical decision of the pope.
A pope declaring someone a canonized saint is clearly not to be taken lightly, as papal infallibility is believed to be invested here. The Church must remain free to render her final decisions in a total honest and unbiased manner without any preconceived ideas from the Catholic faithful from Catholic authors about the sanctity of certain people or about certain private revelations.

Papal infallibility and canonization
Is the pope infallible in issuing a decree of canonization? Most theologians answer in the affirmative. It is the opinion of St. Antoninus, Melchior Cano, Suarez, Bellarmine, Bañez, Vasquez, and, among the canonists, of Gonzales Tellez, Fagnanus, Schmalzgrüber, Barbosa, Reiffenstül, Covarruvias (Variar. resol., I, x, no 13), Albitius (De Inconstantiâ in fide, xi, no 205), Petra (Comm. in Const. Apost., I, in notes to Const. I, Alex., III, no 17 sqq.), Joannes a S. Thomâ (on II-II, Q. I, disp. 9, a. 2), Silvester (Summa, s.v. Canonizatio), Del Bene (De Officio Inquisit. II, dub. 253), and many others. In Quodlib. IX, a. 16, St. Thomas says: "Since the honour we pay the saints is in a certain sense a profession of faith, i.e., a belief in the glory of the Saints [quâ sanctorum gloriam credimus] we must piously believe that in this matter also the judgment of the Church is not liable to error." These words of St. Thomas, as is evident from the authorities just cited, all favouring a positive infallibility, have been interpreted by his school in favour of papal infallibility in the matter of canonization, and this interpretation is supported by several other passages in the same Quodlibet*. - Beatification and Canonization


It's interesting that many LDS answers carry a similar disclaimer:  Disclaimer: these thoughts are the product of my own study and do not constitute official statements by The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints
